# Using Google Maps drawingmanager, getCenter for overlay type circle

Tags: google-maps, geometry

getCenter of the circle object is worked until last week. Now it is not working.

```
The return value center: L
lat: function ()
lng: function ()
```

It comes in.

I would like to know the coordinates of the center.

my source code

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete',function(event){

    drawingManager.setMap(null);

        if (event.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE) {

            circleInfo[0]=event.overlay;
            console.log(event);
            console.log(event.overlay.center);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The center property returns a [LatLng object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng).

So you do:

```
 console.log(event.overlay.center.lat());
 console.log(event.overlay.center.lng());
```

Or even:

```
console.log(event.overlay.center.toString());
```